# Reprojecting using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

Problems trying to reproject the DEM raster layer onto the city layer:

The base layer (CITY) is using NAD_1983 StatePlane Georgia West FIPS1002 feet (WKID:2240) projected CRS with a geographic CS: GCS_NAD1983 (WKID:4269)

Raster Dataset extent: Elevation surface for Cobb County, GA including City of Austell.
West: -89.857908 East:-89.718310
North 40.249497 South: 40.090210

What I have tried :

1. I tried raster functions -> reproject
2. I tried creating an unknown_CS layer, overwrite the original DEM coordinates then define it again with the town coordinates using **DEFINE PROJECTION**
3. I tried "project raster" tool

Yet the layers still do not align properly, though when I view the meta of the DEM file, the stated projected CRS and geographic CS are the same. What is causing this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a. what projection the original unmodified raster is in, before you did anything to it and b. whether you ran the Project Raster tool on the original unmodified raster.  Note you should normally never use "Define Projection". It is only for use when the projection is undefined and you know *exactly* what it is supposed to be. Overwriting raster coordinates (the geotransform) and redefining the projection is never going to work.

Comment: the original DEM does not have a projection (i don't see any spatial references in the metadata), so I tried different reprojection tools)

Comment: Then you need to figure out what the raster projection is. Once you know that, you can use Define Projection to assign the correct projection and only then can you use Project Raster to reproject to the same projection as your city layer. Start by editing your question to add the origin coordinates and pixel/cell size of the raster and some information about where you got the raster from.

Comment: where can i figure out the raster projection except from viewing the metadata? The source of the raster data is unknown (provided by instructor)

Comment: As previously requested, start by [editing your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/387199/edit) to add the origin coordinates and pixel/cell size of the raster.

Comment: It's in a geographic CRS. I'd try setting your map/dataframe coordinate system to GCS_NAD1983 (4269), loading the original DEM and seeing if the city layer overlaps well, if not try WGS84 (4326). If either works, then use define projection tool to set your DEM to the CRS and you can then use Project Raster to reproject to NAD_1983 StatePlane if you need to.

Comment: The raster extent looks wrong. Marietta, Georgia is around 34N, 84.5W. When you see lat/lon coordinates that are west (and usually south) of where the data should be, what has happened is that the data was in lat/lon but had a projected CRS defined for it. The data was then 'unprojected' to lat/lon.